# open solaris code vs solaris code

Tags: solaris, opensolaris

How compatible is code written under Solaris with Open Solaris ? I would be interested specifically in some kernel modules .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel modules in particular will be very compatible between Solaris and OpenSolaris. OpenSolaris (via Project Indiana) is evolving the user-space components more heavily, including the installer and packages.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is hard to quantify software compatibility, but I'd say code written for Solaris is quite forward compatible with OpenSolaris kernel. OpenSolaris source code evolves into what will be Solaris 11, and Sun's commitment to backwards compatibility is quite a fact.

Answer (score 2):

Kernel modules written for Solaris should function in OpenSolaris following a simple recompile providing you are using the exposed kernel APIs that are compatible between the releases that you are using in Solaris and OpenSolaris.

There is a huge amount of work in Sun to ensure that programs written using publicly exposed interfaces are compatible. There is a listed 'Exposure/Stability' entry at the bottom of manual pages for most APIs that state in defined terms how someone can use it.

Answer (score 1):

This is with regard to core OS daemons only and **not** kernel modules, but I've had success compiling OpenSolaris components from source and using the resulting binaries on commercial Solaris just fine. It's obviously easier with a Makefile but I did one manually.

I tried this with a small handful of binaries that I needed to add debugging output to and compiled them directly on the commercial Solaris system using gcc without issue. As mentioned earlier YMMV based on what app/module it is.